# ggplot2 scale_y_log10 not working with stacked geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, logarithm, stacked-chart

```
structure(list(Hypothesis = c("H0", "H0", "H0", "H0", "H0", "H0", 
"H0", "H0", "H0", "H0", "H0", "H0", "H0", "H0", "H0", "H0", "H0", 
"H0", "H0", "H0", "H0", "H0", "H0", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", 
"H1", "H1"), PP = c(9.26073693450588e-29, 3.34281982011265e-24, 
9.38662550316043e-15, 7.95890908425815e-06, 2.86082492381069e-28, 
2.20405950836506e-13, 9.0925912086661e-35, 2.31002748754231e-42, 
4.76347929684044e-23, 1.38383109879787e-23, 2.86033450403371e-19, 
1.18097638779878e-220, 1.10136930662603e-20, 3.34955010022165e-17, 
1.12279490220994e-28, 3.58934964238325e-21, 4.82006911711899e-21, 
2.3176322957431e-273, 3.65469210312312e-23, 1.035293515573e-60, 
1.03909796125627e-46, 0, 1.72578715346419e-21, 0.096735363503543, 
3.97631648427947e-16, 0.00403790620239148, 0.235149734366432, 
0.298832898846241, 0.0948134291565298, 0.160951055566603)), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to plot a histogram with `:

```
p<-ggplot(t,aes(x=PP,fill=Hypothesis))+
geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01)
p
```

[image]

If I use `scale_y_log10()` the values on Y axis get bigger rather than log scaled

```
p<-ggplot(t,aes(x=PP,fill=Hypothesis))+
geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01)+
scale_y_log10()
```

**Any idea why the count for PP = 0 becomes higher ?**

[image: log scale]

Comment: would the transformation results in infinite values

Comment: @akrun even if I use sqrt transformation the values on y axis are getting bigger

Comment: if you do the conversion, there are some -Inf values, i.e. `log10(t$PP)`

Comment: Try with `position = 'dodge` in `geom_histogram`

Comment: yes you are right it is working thanks !

Comment: I posted my comment as a solution.  thanks

Comment: See also discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62195385/11374827

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `position= 'dodge'`

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(t, aes(x = PP, fill = Hypothesis))+
   geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01, position = 'dodge')+
   scale_y_log10()
```