# Why is the transformation of my y-axis to logarithmic scale not showing the correct values in a column plot made with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, scale, logarithm

I am making a plot of columns whose values are very far apart from each other. To solve this, I chose to use logarithmic scaling on the y-axis with the function `scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10')`. But in doing so, the values displayed on the y-axis are totally different from the real ones. How can I solve this?

```
library(ggplot2)

Place <- c("A", "B", "C")
Class <- c("a", "b", "c")
Value <- c(1,2,3,10,20,30,100,200,300)

DF <- expand.grid(Place = Place,
            Class = Class)

DF$Value <- Value 

ggplot(data = DF,
     aes(x = Place,
         y = Value,
         group = Class)) +
 geom_col(aes(fill = Class)) +
 geom_text(aes(label = Value),
           position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
 scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10')
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't stack the bars, you can dodge them instead. Bar stacking occurs after scale transformations, so the height are effectively `log(A) + log(B) = log(A * B)` instead of the more technically correct `log(A + B)`. See also the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62195385/11374827

Comment: @teunbrand, please post that as an answer ... unless you think this is a duplicate of your linked answer.

Comment: The phrasing is slightly different but the underlying problem is the same, so I've marked it a duplicate.