# How to make log10 ONLY first y-axis (not secondary y-axis) in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I would like to plot **ONLY** y-axis1 DATA (left axis, Var1, dotted line) as a log10 scale. The dotted line would therefore look higher on the y-axis and differences between 1 and 2 would be noticeable.

I have tried several things, but does not work ( I believe I am using them in the wrong order/place) such as:

`+coord_trans(y='log10')`--> empty plot

`scale_y_continuous(trans = log10_trans()`,... --> makes both Var1 and Var 2 log10

`scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))`--> makes both y axis log10 and removes y-axis2 (Var2)

```
data<- data.frame(
      Day=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
      Name=rep(c(rep("a",3),rep("b",3),rep("c",3))),
      Var1=c(1090,484,64010,1090,484,64010,1090,484,64010),
      Var2= c(4,16,39,2,22,39,41,10,3))


ggplot(data)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=Name, y=Var2*1000, x=Day),stat="identity", colour="black", position= position_stack(reverse = TRUE))+
  geom_line(aes(x=Day, y=Var1),stat="identity",color="black", linetype="dotted", size=0.8)+
  geom_point(aes(Day, Var1), shape=8)+
  labs(title= "",
       x="",y=expression('Var1'))+
  scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis=sec_axis(~./1000, name= expression(paste("Var2"))))+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_grey(start = 1, end=0.1,name = "", labels = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

[image]

Comment: Just as a heads up, stacked bars and log-scales might not work as you'd expect, see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62195385/11374827). If you can, avoid it.

Comment: @teunbrand thanks for pointing that out. I will have a deep read this eve. However, what I would like to plot in log10 is Var1 (the dotted line). and therefore should not affect it that much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to have the primary axis be the linear one, but put it on the right side of the plot. Then, you can have the secondary one be your log-transformed axis.

```r
library(ggplot2)

data<- data.frame(
  Day=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
  Name=rep(c(rep("a",3),rep("b",3),rep("c",3))),
  Var1=c(1090,484,64010,1090,484,64010,1090,484,64010),
  Var2= c(4,16,39,2,22,39,41,10,3))

# Max of secondary divided by max of primary
upper <- log10(3e6) / 80

breakfun <- function(x) {
  10^scales::extended_breaks()(log10(x))
}

ggplot(data)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=Name, y=Var2, x=Day),
           stat="identity", colour="black", position= position_stack(reverse = TRUE))+
  geom_line(aes(x=Day, y=log10(Var1) / upper),
            stat="identity",color="black", linetype="dotted", size=0.8)+
  geom_point(aes(Day, log10(Var1) / upper), shape=8)+
  labs(title= "",
       x="",y=expression('Var1'))+
  scale_y_continuous(
    position = "right",
    name = "Var2",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~10^ (. * upper), name= expression(paste("Var1")),
                        breaks = breakfun)
  )+
  theme_classic() +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 1, end=0.1,name = "", labels = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: wow great! @teunbrand this looks like what I was looking for thank you. Why are you using the log10 on the function, but then log2 within the plot code?

Comment: if I'd like to determine the limits narrower  within the sec.axis  such as limits = c(0, 3E+06)? @teunbrand I got an error

Comment: I've edited it to set a maximum. A log axis cannot start from 0, because `log(0)` is evaluated as `-Inf`. I used the `log10()` for the breaks because it gives nicer numbers than `log2()`. In the edit I used `log10()` throughout

Answer (score 1):

Here is a custom breaks function:

```r
br <- function(limits) {
  10^(seq(ifelse(limits[1] <= 0,
                 0,
                 trunc(log10(limits[1]))),
          trunc(log10(limits[2])),
          by = 1))}
```

```r
ggplot(data)  + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Name, y = Var2 * 1000, x = Day),
           stat = "identity",
           colour = "black",
           position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))+
  geom_line(aes(x=Day, y=Var1),
            stat = "identity",
            color = "black",
            linetype = "dotted",
            size = 0.8)+
  geom_point(aes(Day, Var1),
             shape = 8)+
  labs(title = "",
       x = "",
       y = expression('Var1'))+
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = br,
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~./1000, name= expression(paste("Var2"))))+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_fill_grey(start = 1,
                  end = 0.1,
                  name = "",
                  labels = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

Results aren't so pretty but you can customize the breaks as you wish.

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sbarbit seems like you have suggested an axis converted to log10, However, I must have not explained well, what I actually want is the data ploted as log10, so the line between 1-2-3 would look higher on the y axis. and the differences between a and b would be better seen.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely should read the answer @teunbrand linked to in the comment to your question.  But for the matter of displaying log values on the left and original values on the right, you can use:

```
tibble(Day = 1:10,
       Val1 =10*Day) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Day, y = log10(Val1))) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_y_log10(name = "log(Val1)",
                  sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 10^., name = "Val1"))
```